# Sync Center: Connecting to a synced remote folder

Tags: windows-8, authentication

Before enabling Sync Center on a remote folder, when I clicked a link to that folder Windows asked me for login details and once I entered them I got to access the folder.

Now I've enabled Sync Center, I do access the local copy of the directory, but it fails to sync. "Right click on systray -> Synchronize all" does nothing.

I guess the problem is authentication, since even previously Windows always failed to remember credentials (even if I did check the "remember" box), but I can't find were I'm supposed to enter my login.

If I try to browse that server now I just get "not accessible" errors, instead of the login prompt as I got before.

I have no clue what I'm supposed to do to actually make the sync work.
(if I don't have to re-enter the password every time it would be better, but that's not required)

Comment: After 1 day and like 4 reboots, finally it asked me for credentials again. No clue what triggered it, hence the question stands, since it might happen again.

Comment: Still have this problem, it only works when it feels to, and gives zero feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove authenticated credentials from Windows by :

- Control Pane -> User Accounts -> Manage your credentials -> share name,
  click down arrow on the share to expose the "Remove from vault" option.
- Once the above is done, in cmd as administrator do :
  `net use * /DELETE`